# How to access a text object by name in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c++, crystal-reports, c++builder-6

In C++Builder 6, how can I access a text object by name in Crystal Reports, so I can set its text? This is what I have right now:

```
crp->TextObjects[0].Items[0]->Lines->SetText("Text");
```

Comment: It helps if you reveal what errror message you get. Is it a compilation error?

Comment: @TedLyngmo this code is set text by text objects item index, but i want by object name

Comment: _"i want by object name"_ -. well, I actually think that's possible in C++ Builder and you'll probably get answers later, but I've rarely used it myself. If there's an error, please show it so that the people knowing about this stuff get some information.

Comment: First, I don't think `TextObjects` is an array, so you should use `TextObjects->` instead of `TextObjects[0].` to access its members. Second, BCB6 is ancient, and I can't find any documentation on such an old version of Crystal Reports. But chances are, if `TextObjects` doesn't provide a method to find a `TextObject` by name, then you will likely have to manually enumerate the objects looking for one yourself, eg: `for(int i = 0; i < crp->TextObjects->Count; ++i) { if (crp->TextObjects->Items[i]->Name == "...") { ... break; } }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could not find member 'Name' in Items[i]

Comment: @Alan obviously, you would have to use the correct property/method name. Like I said, I couldn't find any documentation for such an old Crystal Reports version. But if an object can be assigned a name, there has to be a way to query that name from the object.